# Vue2 router do not work when type manually

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have such code:

```
created: function() {
    if(!localStorage.hasOwnProperty('auth_token')) {
        router.replace({name: 'login'});
    } else {
         if(router.history.current.name == 'login') {
             router.push({name: 'allVideos'});
         }
    }
}
```

inside my Vue root instance .

So when page is loading it checks the token. When I do not have a token I'm redirecting to login page. If I have a token redirect to allVideos if on login page, or do not redirect at all if on other pages.

All is work fine when I made refresh, go through some buttons etc. But when I manually type /#/login and press enter Vue render login page but auth_token exist. And when I type manually it do not get to `created` method at all. When I type again /#/login from login page again it start working.... Any ideas ??? Thanks

**Update:** Well I'm tried to use navigation guards

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty('auth_token')) {
        if(to.name == 'login') {
            next({name: 'allVideos'});
        }
    } else {
        if(to.name != 'login') {
            next({path: '/login'});
        }
    }
        next();

});
```

Code now much cleaner as for me, but issue is still there when I'm typing manually

Comment: I think the concept is not right here.Instead of putting those things Vue into instance, I think you should go with some navigation guard, in your case `router.beforeEach` should do the trick https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: You mean instead of adding such code to `created` method I should use `beforeEach` hook? will check, do not read about that yet.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, check this example here https://github.com/TahaSh/spa-forum/blob/master/resources/assets/js/main.js#L56 - (note this is Vue 1 and old router code, but it could help you) 
beforeEach is not lifecycle hook, it's navigation guard from router instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `next()` is called 2 times so it creates the problem. You can try this code:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty('auth_token')) {
    if(to.name === 'login') {
      next({name: 'allVideos'});
    }
  } else if(to.name !== 'login') {
    next({path: '/login'})
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```